# Error when updating a N-M table value with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need help, i've been trying to update a N-M relation table element with no success i get an error

```
TypeError: this.set is not a function
    at model.funcs.(anonymous function) (/sandbox/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:1103:25)
```

when i call result.save().
I guess i'm doing something wrong:

```
Model.SetPart.findOne({
        include: [Model.Part, Model.Set],
        where: { "$part.RebrickableId$": "15392", "$set.RebrickableId$": "75198-1" }
    })
        .then(result => {
            result.Quantity = 2;
            return result.save();
        })
        .then(() => {
            res.send("Updated...");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            res.send(/*JSON.stringify(err)*/ "Problem :( " + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
```

that is probably something really dumb but i've been looking and i can't seem to find what the problem is! Can someone help? thanks!

Comment: the problem seem to be with my 'Include' for some reason if i remove that and use an id for the 'where' my save works fine...

Comment: also, if i remove the Model.Set includes, it seems to solve the problem, so i guess maybe the name of the Model is problematic?